# Meteor: Disable calling automatically on iOS when tapping on phone number

Tags: ios, meteor

I am using Meteor Framework.

The following code

```
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```

or

```
<a href="tel:+1 (123) 456-7890">(123) 456-7890</a>
```

Initiates a call automatically in iOS.

I need some kind of warning.. such as pop up saying

> Call 123-456-7890 ?

and if the user wants to call then they can press Call or else Cancel.

How do I fix this on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

*First*, you could **wrap the call link inside a pop up or modal**. In your template:

```
<a class="open-popup">Call 123-456-7890</a>
```

Open the pop up via click event. In Meteor you can do this like this:

```
Template.myTemplateName.events({
        "click a.open-popup": function(event) { 
          // Open pop up ...
        });
```

In this pop up you place the link `<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>` alongside with a cancle button, which is nothing else than a pop up closer. `<a class="close-popup">cancle</a>`

*Second*, use a click event with **`confirm()` function and then do a url redirect to the `tel://´** address.

```
Template.myTemplateName.events({
"click a.open-popup": function(event) {
  var r = confirm("Call 123-456-7890 ?");
  if (r == true) {
    let phoneNumber = "123-456-7890";
      window.location.href="tel://"+phoneNumber;
  } else {
      // closes
  }
});
```

I guess, the second option is easier to implement and already does, what you are looking for.

Comment: What if there are multiple numbers on template "myTemplateName"? how do I create event for each of the number? Should I create multiple var and keep keep if ( r == true || p == true ....) ? Also how to I put the tag on HTML to reference this JS event?